# export node module to local error

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am a newby on node.js. i want to parse a xml file into json .so i am trying to use bulebutton library from https://github.com/blue-button/bluebutton.js . 
first i have installed the module by command npm install bluebutton and its created a node_modules folder with bluebutton module.
now i created a test.js file with following code

```
var bb = require('bluebutton');
var myRecord = bb.BlueButton('./asd.xml');
console.log(myRecord);
```

but its gave me an error that bluebutton is not define .please help me to figureout this problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

REVISED ANSWER
From bluebuttonjs.com/docs, the require statement you use would return the BlueButton object, so bb represents said object, and it would be called like so

```
var myRecord = bb('someFile.xml');
```

However you might also note that they use fs to read the file before passing it. http://www.bluebuttonjs.com/docs/#parsing-node

PREVIOUS ANSWER (for wrong module)
According to their npm docs, you need to do

```
var bb = require('blue-button');
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/blue-button

Comment: no its a different module its bluebutton not blue-button